# How to run a gradle project on eclipse exp project: https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-android-chat

Tags: java, android

Just a beginner in android,
Was trying to learn Android and socket IO interaction. So picked up a opensource hello world project as mentioned. But I am not getting how to run such gradle project to my virtual AVD. I have eclipse and Android sdk on ubuntu 14.04. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can generate eclipse project by using [gradle eclipse plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html).
In your `build.gradle`,

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
```

and with running the following gradle task,

```
$ gradle eclipse
```

eclipse project will be generated. Another solution would be just using the [gradle plugin for eclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle-integration-eclipse-0).

But I strongly recommend you to switch your IDE to [AndroidStdio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/) when it comes to Android development.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple trick to import Android Studio Projects in Eclipse.

1. Create a new Android Project on Eclipse with default settings.
2. Go to the workspace folder and open the project folder.
3. Now in parallel, open the gradle project in another folder.
4. Open the main application folder where the following folders/files will be there: java, res and AndroidManifest.xml
5. In you eclipse project (that you just created) folder, open the src folder and delete the contents of the folder. Now paste the contents of the java folder (the one mentioned in step 4) (it will contain the complete source code)
6. In you eclipse project (that you just created) folder, open the res folder and delete the contents of the folder. Now paste the contents of the res folder (the one mentioned in step 4) (it will contain all the resources of the project)
7. In you eclipse project (that you just created) folder, you will also see the AndroidManifest.xml. Now replace it with the AndroidManifest.xml of the gradle project (the one mentioned in step 4).
8. Now go back to Eclipse, select the project you just created, hit F5 (to refresh the contents). Clean the project.

**Note: If there are any library dependencies for the project, you will have to locate it on the internet (or locate them if available in the gradle project) and copy it in the libs folder for you eclipse project. If the library is given as another project, follow the above steps again, right click on the library-project, and check the *is Library* option and import it as library in the application project.**

Hope this helped. Cheers :)